# ruby on rails on click events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio, events, button

I am so sorry if this question seems too easy but I can't seem to find it anywhere. I am creating a ruby in steel project. I have created a html.erb and rb file in a vs project (ruby on rails).

My problem is the following:
In my html1.erb file I have created a text box and button:

```
<p>
<input erb:blockvar="erb:f" erb:method="erb::myName" erb:name="erb:text_field" 
    name="erb:f[:myName]" size="30" type="text" /><input erb:blockvar="erb:f" 
    erb:method="erb:&quot;myValue&quot;" erb:name="erb:submit" name="erb:f[myName]" 
    type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
```

But I have no idea how to create an event for this button.

Any pointers please??

thank you!

Comment: That doesn't look like any rails code i've ever seen.

Comment: im guessing its converted into another language..i have no idea..im totally lost. i just added the textbox and button and this is the code it generated

Comment: Are you coming from a asp.net background? The reason I ask is because Rails doesn't have server side events like asp.net.

Comment: actually yes...im finding it hard to adapt to the rails world actually

Answer (score 1):

I have a sneaking suspicion that the code being generated is some concoction of [Ruby in Steel](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/). If that is the sort of code being generated I would recommend against even using that IDE product since ***NO*** Ruby/Rails coder will understand it if you ever need to bring them into your project. Never mind that I am at a loss to see how it could even work unless Ruby in Steel is doing some intermediate "compilation" step. If you need an IDE I personally recommend [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/), although [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.org/) is a worthy offering as well (and free).